# F (Fill Faces) Doesnt work in Blender

Tags: faces

The F key doesnt work for some faces I try to fill. In the middle part i can fill the face. [image][image]

But if i try to fill the back it doesnt work.
[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

sometimes normals can mess up the fill function, try resetting and reallocating outside.
If that doesn't work and its only 2 problem areas, you can just extrude an edge and merge its extrusion to the vertices on the edge of the mirror.

Answer (score 0):

To fill a face, select all vertices building the face. Keep in mind it means at least 3 vertices (a triangle). If you select less vertices, the operator might still succeed by guessing which additional vertices you want but were lazy enough not to select them. "Might" is the key word here, it depends on the topology of the surrounding geometry (I don't know the exact algorithm).

Comment: Okay that works but the next problem is that when i press Ctrl + R and try to do a cut it doesnt select the one back i mentioned in the last picture.